# How can I change the website document root?

Tags: cakephp

I want to move to my document root from public_html to public_html/new_version/.  I did this using .htaccess

```
RewriteRule    ^$    new_version/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) new_version/$1    [L]
```

It works fine but the links in my CakePHP application are appearing: `domain.com/new_version/the-link-is-shown-here/`

I want to either change completely the document root or have the links appear without the "/new_version/" folder name in them.

Comment: `I want to either change completely the document root` - why don't you do exactly that, make your apache host point at `whatever/app/new_version` instead of `whatever`.

Comment: @AD7six That's definitely the best thing to do. But "public_html" hints at CPanel and possibly shared hosting :) In which case he wouldn't be able to change the document root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `App.baseUrl` config in core.php to `/`.

Comment: I tried that, it gave me broken links on everything. all static resources links are prepended with /app/webroot/ for example: /app/webroot/favicon.ico @ADmad